# How to override spring property param with Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have defined property in `Spring` application.

```
@Configuration
public class WebappConfiguration {

    @Value("${ext.storage.path}")
    private String extDirectoryPath;

    public String getExtDirectoryPath() {
        return extDirectoryPath;
    }
}
```

Default value for `ext.storage.path` property is defined in `application.properties` file.

*application.properties*

```
ext.storage.path=/home/user/ext/
```

When I deploy `WAR` to tomcat with VM options `-Dext.storage.path=/var/webapp-data/`, this value is loaded successfully. But I would like to load property values more smarter from context files for every environment.

So I deploy the `WAR` to `ROOT` of Tomcat, name of WAR file is `ROOT.war` and it is exploded to `ROOT` directory. I created `context` file on path `{CATALINA_BASE}/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml` with following content.

*ROOT.xml*

```
<Context 
        docBase="/opt/webapp-tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war"
        path=""
        reloadable="true">

        <Parameter name="ext.storage.path" value="file:/var/webapp-data/" override="true"/>

</Context>
```

Unfortunately, the param is not loaded according to the way, it has default value from `application.properties`.

**EDIT:**
After a little investigation, I put the `Parameter` into main `context.xml` file of Tomcat and the value is overridden.

```
<Parameter name="ext.storage.path" value="file:/var/webapp-data/" override="true"/>
```

Comment: Try to put it in JNDI with the same name instead of a parameter. It should still do a lookup. You might want to enable debug/trace logging for spring that way you can see what is loaded where and consulted where.

Answer (score 1):

The best technique I know of is to put environment-specific stuff into Tomcat's conf/context.xml file.

```
  <Environment name="myApp/extStoragePath" type="java.lang.String" value="/var/data/myapp"/>
```

This defines a JNDI variable that you lookup in your code with something like this:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
String extStoragePath = (String) envCtx.lookup("myApp/extStoragePath");
```

You can also use this technique to load complex objects like database datasources etc. It has huge advantages:

- The configuration is personal to the environment, not the application
- You don't need to mess with Tomcat startup scripts
- The same binary will run in DEV, UAT and PROD without modification. This much simplifies the build process.

Also, Spring provides a `org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean` which can access JNDI from your spring configuration files.

Comment: But I try to define specific stuff in context.xml but Tomcat define three equivalent ways: *In an individual file at `/META-INF/context.xml`, * In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` directory. * Inside a Host element in the main `conf/server.xml`. I know that there is not required to define another code for loading values. Tomcat initialize the values automatically from individual path.

Comment: Okay, I know benefits of your proposal. It's the same way what I'm using, but you don't write me relevant solution.

Comment: >>"But I would like to load property values more smarter from context files for every environment." Can you tell us why JNDI is not a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Because I want to preserve this way. I have experience with JNDI only with loading datasources to DB.