# How to read Tomcat Environment entries with Spring JNDITemplate

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a small Spring application running in TomEE.  In the Tomee Context.xml file, I define an environment entry with a defined name which I can successfully look up in my application context with "jee:jndi-lookup".

I also have a datasource Resource defined in the tomee.xml file, which I can lookup with JNDITemplate.lookup() using a name of "openejb:Resource/foo", if my datasource "id" property is "foo".

What I'm unable to figure out is how to lookup an environment entry with JNDITemplate.  If the Environment "name" attribute is "foo", what do I enter for the argument to "lookup()"?  I've tried numerous variations, and I can't get anything to work.

One thing that I've always found frustrating with JNDI is that it seems like it's hard to write a little bit of test code that just prints out everything in the environment, so I can see what I should be looking for.  Quite often I've ended up having to simply guess what the prefix is.

Answer (score 0):

A simple class to find all the properties in spring application(it includes System properties) :

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
        for(Iterator it = ((AbstractEnvironment) env).getPropertySources().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            PropertySource propertySource = (PropertySource) it.next();
            if (propertySource instanceof MapPropertySource) {
                map.putAll(((MapPropertySource) propertySource).getSource());
            }
        }

        map.entrySet().forEach( entry -> System.out.println("key "+entry.getKey()+" value "+entry.getValue()));
    }

}
```

if want to change the lookup name dynamically, consider using @Value("${jndi.name}")

Comment: Interesting code, but when I added it to the beginning of the block when I'm trying to do JNDI lookups, I noticed that it printed out lots of properties, but nothing in the JNDI tree.

Comment: could you please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321414/how-to-override-spring-property-param-with-tomcat